# Image is not showing in the post. In Django, post.image is not showing the image in blogHome.html and blogPost.html page

Tags: html, django

I have two apps in my django project home and blog. All the post related coding is in the blog app. I am fetching the data from Post model.
here is the coding of blogHome.html template

```
{% extends base.html %}
    <h1>Posts Results By Ayyal Ayuro Care</h1>
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3 my-4">
            {% for post in allPosts %}
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card shadow-sm">
                    <img src="{{post.image}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3>Post by {{post.author}}</h3>
                        <h4>{{post.title}}</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">
                        <div class="preview">{{post.content|safe| truncatechars:150 }}</div>
                        </p>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a href="{{post.slug}}" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">View More</a>
                            </div>
                            <small class="text-muted">{{post.timestamp}}</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
    
        </div>
```

here is the coding of the blogPost.html. when someone click on the view more button in blogHome.html page it shws up blogPost.html page. But Images are not showing in this page also.

```
{% extends base.html %}    
<div class="container my-4">
      <img src="{{post.image}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <h2 class="blog-post-title">{{post.title}}</h2>
      <p class="blog-post-meta">{{post.timestamp}} by <a href="#">{{post.author}}</a></p>
      <p>{{post.content|safe}}</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
```

here is my views.py file of blog app

```
from django.contrib.auth import models
from django.http import response
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, HttpResponse
from datetime import datetime
from home.models import Comment
from blog.models import Post
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your views here.
def blogHome(request): 
    allPosts = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'allPosts': allPosts}
    return render(request, 'blog/blogHome.html', context)
    # return HttpResponse("This is Herbal Drugs Page")
    #return HttpResponse('This is  blog home. We will keep all blog posts here')

def blogPost(request, slug): 
    post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    comment = Comment.objects.filter(post=post, parent=None)
    replies = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).exclude(parent=None)
    replyDict = {}
    for reply in replies:
        if reply.parent.sno not in replyDict.keys():
            replyDict[reply.parent.sno] = [reply]
        else:
            replyDict[reply.parent.sno].append(reply)
    context = {'post': post, 'comments': comment, 'user': request.user, 'replyDict': replyDict}
    return render(request, 'blog/blogPost.html', context)
    #return HttpResponse(f'This is blogPost : {slug}')
```

here is urls.py file of blog app

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blogHome, name="bloghome"),
    path('<str:slug>', views.blogPost, name="blogPost"),
]
```

The images are in the images floder under static. Evry field in the post is working except the post.image. When i add a new post it shows all the contents but not the image. [this is the image how the posts shows in the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEhdS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<img src="{{post.image}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
```

use

```
<img src="{{post.image.url}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
```

Comment: Glad it helped! kindly mark this answer as accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers